# how to convert a date HH: MM: SS in second with bash?

Tags: bash, date

How to convert a date HH: MM: SS in second with bash?

Knowing that this is a date that I recovered in a file so I can't take it in another format.

I have two variables $DateStart and $DateEnd and i would like the difference between both.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
date +%s
```

returns the current datetime in seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

if you want to get a given datetime in seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, for example:

```
kent$  date -d"2008-08-08 20:20:20" +%s
1218219620
```

to get diff in seconds, you just get the two dates in seconds, and do a `s1-s2`

Comment: Note that if timestamps don't contain dates, `date` should still be supplied with them. Otherwise, if only times are passed, `date` will assume today and times calculated on either side of midnight will have additional 24 hour difference between them.

Comment: Thanks it's works, i do start=$(date -d"$DateStart" +%s) and end=$(date -d"$DateEnd" +%s) and after time=$(end-start).

Answer (score 10):

On a Mac (and probably other BSDs) you can convert a date into another date with a combination of the `-j` and `-f` option:

```
$ date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' "2016-02-22 20:22:14" '+%s'
1456168934
```

Where `-j` suppresses changing the system clock,
`-f <fmt>` gives the format to use for parsing the given date,
`"2016-02-22 20:22:14"` is the input date and
`+<fmt>` is the output format.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the time in HH:MM:SS format is in variable `time_hhmmss` and time in
seconds needs to be stored in `time_s`:

```
IFS=: read -r h m s <<<"$time_hhmmss"
time_s=$(((h * 60 + m) * 60 + s))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use my solution with sed+awk:

```
echo $DateStart | sed 's/:\|-/ /g;' | awk '{print $4" "$3" "$2" "$1}' | awk '{print $1+$2*60+$3*3600+$4*86400}'
echo $DateEnd | sed 's/:\|-/ /g;' | awk '{print $4" "$3" "$2" "$1}' | awk '{print $1+$2*60+$3*3600+$4*86400}'
```

it splits the string with sed, then inverts the numbers backwards ("DD hh mm ss" -> "ss mm hh DD") and calculates them with awk.
It works even you add days: [[DD-]hh:]mm:ss, eg:

> ```
>        34:56
>     12:34:56
> 123-12:34:56
> ```

Comment: This is good but appears to only work down to the minute. Seconds get rounded.

Answer (score 0):

When using the above examples remember to add -u (to use GMT) otherwise 1970-01-01 00:00:00 is not zero :-)

```
$ date -d"1970-01-01 00:00:00" +%s
-3600

$ date -u -d"1970-01-01 00:00:00" +%s
0
```